# How the preseve the state of toggle buttons in a list?

Tags: android, listview, togglebutton

I have a list(with uncertain numbers of items) with toggle button. Every time I press back button, and enter that page again, all toggle button become off as state in xml. How can I get the position of the toggle button and "setChecked" it ? or any method to check the toggle button I checked (set to ON) before

Comment: I guess that pressing the Back button trigger the `onCreate()` method again and the toggle buttons are set to the default? If so, then you need to save those preferences I guess?

Comment: saving it in your adapter model as boolean flag..., and in adapter getview based on that boolean showing the state of the toggle btn... and on each toggle/checked update the adapter model

Comment: Are you using adapter to render listview?

Answer (score 0):

Use `onPause()` to save the state of your toggle buttons :

```
    bundle.putBoolean("ToggleButtonState", toggleButton.isChecked());
```

Use `onResume()` to retrieve the state of toggle buttons :

```
   toggleButton.setChecked(bundle.getBoolean("ToggleButtonState",false));
```